# Is there a difference between 'expect' and 'should' in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

For example, these two tests:

```
it "fails to create given a bad player list" do
  Team.new("Random name", bad_players).should raise_error
end
```

and

```
it "fails to create given a bad player list" do
  expect {Team.new("Random name", bad_players)}.to raise_error
end
```

They return different outputs (the first one fails, while the 2nd one passes).  I would expect both to either pass or fail depending on the contents of the Team model.

The full RSpec code is:

```
require_relative 'team'

describe "Team" do

  it "has a name" do
    Team.new("Random name").should respond_to(:name)
  end

  it "has a list of players" do
    Team.new("Random name").players.should be_kind_of Array
  end

  it "is favored if it has a celebrity on it"
  it "complains if there is a bad word in the name"

  context "given a bad list of players" do
    let(:bad_players) { {} }

    it "fails to create given a bad player list" do
      expect { Team.new("Random name", bad_players) }.to raise_error
    end
  end

end
```

The reason I thought 'should' would work is because of the similar syntax in the 'it "has a name"' test.  If it turns out that 'should' is incorrect and 'expect...to' is correct, I would love to know when to use one vs. the other.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md:

> From the beginning `RSpec::Expectations` provided `should` and
>   `should_not` methods to define expectations on any object. In version
>   2.11 `expect` method was introduced which is now the recommended way to define expectations on an object.

The next paragraph in that document describe the difference in implementation and why `expect` is now the recommended approach.

At this point, pretty much anything you can do with `should` and `should_not` can be done with `expect`.  See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames for details and `expect` usage.

As for your specific code, the reason the first example is failing is that the error is occurring before RSpec has a chance to get involved. You can still use `should` to check for the raising of an error, but you have to give RSpec a chance to work. The syntax is `lambda {...}.should raise_error` where `...` is the code you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** this is an old anwser - with recent versionsof RSpec `should` is not recommended anymore. Use the `expect` syntax instead

---

Yes there is a difference

`should` will verify that what's on the rights side is `true`. It must be used for simple comparison of results.

```
(1+1).should eq(3-1)
```

`expect` takes a block and verify that the execution of the block has a specific effect. It must be use when comparing the situation before and after the block is executed

```
expect{ User.new.save }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
```

Use `should` as must as you can (it's easier to write) and `expect` only when `should` is not able to do the job

Comment: In fact, using `should` is not recommended anymore. use `expect` instead.

Comment: Thank you for this precision on an 8 years old answer... @svelandiag